# Dataset Crashes Information and Definition functions

Tags: bugs, dataset, symbols

**Bug in 11.0.1 fixed in 11.1.0**

---

Has anyone else noticed this odd function crash with `Dataset`s.  Try the following in a clean kernel.

```
ds = ExampleData[{"Dataset", "Planets"}]

?`*
```

> *Repeated **$RecursionLimit** errors.*

Have to abort evaluation.

```
??`*
```

> *Repeated **$RecursionLimit** errors.*

Have to abort evaluation.

Add a second symbol.

```
x = 1
```

Now both `` ?`* `` and `` ??`* `` complete. However if you select `ds` the  **$RecursionLimit** errors return and you must abort evaluation.

Version 11.0.1 Win 7 Ent

---

CASE:3861310

Comment: `?ds` is sufficient to trigger the problem.  If there are two symbols, ``?`*`` is no longer equivalent to `?ds`.

Comment: I see this too - 11.0.0 Linux

Comment: Reported to WRI.